# speed up query MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this simple query

```
SELECT *,count(*) as total FROM `Artikels` group by `Manuf_nr` having total >1
```

but it takes about 3 seconds to get results. Is there anyway I can speed it up? Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: How many items do you have? Are there indexes in the database?

Comment: How many columns do you have in the table?  Do you really need all of them?  Also note that `count(1)` will produce the same result as `count(*)` but run faster.

Comment: Show your table definition and run `explain` to see if indexes are used.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are telling mysql to implictly group on the extra columns which can have an impact... I would either do

```
SELECT `Manuf_nr`,count(*) as total FROM `Artikels` group by `Manuf_nr` having count(*)  >1
```

or expand out your `*` and include these in the group by.

You should only go to the level of detail you absolutely need for your query - do you need the first set of details for every `Manuf_nr` or do you just need the `Manuf_nr`s with more than 1 record?

Answer (score 0):

Making sure `Manuf_nr` is indexed will make the most difference.

You also want to select only the fields you're interested in, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your script will give strange results as the columns other than Manuf_nr from Artikels will be from undefined rows (ie, if 10 rows have the same Manuf_nr then your could would be 10, but which of those 10 rows details was brought back by the select * is not certain).

Assuming an index on Manuf_nr, your SQL should probably be rewritten as something like:-

```
SELECT a.*, b.total
FROM Artikels a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Manuf_nr, count(*) AS total 
    FROM `Artikels` 
    GROUP BY Manuf_nr
) b
ON a.Manuf_nr = b.Manuf_nr 
AND b.total > 1
```

This will bring back all the rows for each Manuf_nr where there are more than one row for that Manuf_nr.